# Error 403 on public page w/ python get request

Tags: python, html, api, get, request

I'm a complete newbie to python and trying to get the content of a webpage with a get request. The page I'm trying to access is public without any authorization as far as I can see. It's a job listing from the career website of a popular company and everyone can view the page.

My code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.tuvsud.com/de-de/karriere/stellen/jobs/projektmanagerin-auditservice-food-corporate-functions-business-support-all-regions-133776'

headers = {
    'Host': '',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

print(r.status_code)
```

However I get the status code 403. With the google url for example it works though.
I would be happy about any help! thanks in advance

Comment: some pages has complex system to detect scripts/bots/hackers/spamers and it may need  something more complex to access data. I think this page uses JavaScript to add elements - so it may also use JavaScript to detect script - because `requests`, `Beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. It may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)` to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

Comment: next time to format code use ``` your code  ``` (or key `Ctrl+K`) instead of `<code>`

Comment: first you should check `print( r.text )` to see full HTML - and you will see it sends Captcha to check if you are human.